# From BIOS to Login screen now takes 20 minutes. How do fix it?

Tags: boot, 13.04, grub2, kernel, bios

When I start my machine, BIOS loads, GRUB loads, then I go from the purple screen to a blank black screen with blinking cursor, login won't appear for 20 minutes or so. Several lines of code appear and seem to indicate something is timing out, but they're not onscreen long enough to read.

This just started yesterday morning. I update daily. Intel Graphics drivers just updated. BIOS up to date.

Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail.

Toshiba Satellite L305-S5915, Celeron M, 2GB RAM

What do I do?

Edit: Thanks to TroyM and TenPlus1, I DL'd the old kernel (-25) and rebooted into it. Works fine.

Comment: I might have run across a similar problem after an update a couple of days ago. I did not wait 20 minutes to see if I got a login screen so I don't know if it is exactly the same problem. I was able to get running by booting the previous kernel version from the grub boot menu (3.8.0-25). I haven't had time to try to diagnose things any further yet.

Comment: That was it! I used Synaptic to get -25 and rebooted. Works like it always did. Thanks, TroyM!

Answer (score 0):

Hold down SHIFT key while booting and the boot menu will appear, from there you can select to use a previous kernel which should hopefully remedy your situation...

Comment: There are no other kernels.

Comment: You were on the right track, TenPlus1. As TroyM suggested, and you did too for that matter, it was the new kernel. I had done something I hadn't done before and purged the old kernels thinking I was OK. WRONG!  :(  Thank you, too!